# Python Recursive Turtle function that draws capital I's

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics

Meant to draw this with turtle using recursion:

[image: https://gyazo.com/4a6d64fd83c1dbf894914bb91c8189b1]

But I'm really bad at this. This is what I'm getting:

[image: https://gyazo.com/ec6ffa37b1792ed08b9260f4e496a953]

Here's the code:
https://gyazo.com/24cebddbb111506fd6959bb91dadb481

```
import turtle
def draw_shape(t, level,size):
    if level == 1: #draws an I
        t.down()
        t.forward(size/2)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(size/2)
        t.back(size)
        t.forward(size/2)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(size/2)
        t.back(size)
        t.up()
        t.forward(size/2)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(size/2)

    else:
        draw_shape(t,level - 1,size)
        t.back(size/2)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(size/2)
        t.left(90)
        draw_shape(t,level - 1,size/2)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(size)
        t.right(90)
        draw_shape(t,level-1,size/2)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(size/2)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(size)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(size/2)
        t.left(90)
        draw_shape(t,level-1,size/2)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(size)
        t.right(90)
        draw_shape(t,level-1,size/2)

def q1():
    my_win = turtle.Screen()
    my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
    my_turtle.speed(0.006)
    my_turtle.left(90)
    my_turtle.up()
    my_turtle.back(200)
    n = int(input('Draw shape at level: '))
    draw_shape(my_turtle,n,200)
    my_win.exitonclick()

q1()
```

Pretty much only meant to edit the draw_shape() function. I'm getting it right at level 2 but the rest of the levels start to go wonky and draw wrong sized I's in the wrong positions and I think it's because of where my pointer is placed after the I's are drawn. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add the code as text in the question? We can't copy and paste a screenshot.

Comment: Not really sure how to thank on Overflow but thanks for helping out with my first post you saved me a lot of hair-pulling because I didn't know how to get the pen back to the centre after each call. Definitely needa go over this a few times to get the hang of recursion. Thanks again I really do appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues with your code as you have it now.

The first is that the lower part of the code doesn't put the turtle back at the center point after it's done. This is why the smaller bits get drawn in various random locations, since the previous calls left the turtle somewhere odd.

The second issue is that you're using a recursive call right at the start. That's not really necessary, since you're going to be moving along the `I` shape later anyway.

What's I'd suggest is making your base case `level < 1`. That doesn't require you to do anything (you can just `return` immediately). This replaces your whole `if level == 1` block (except for `t.down()` which you need to keep).

```
def draw_shape(t, level, size):
    if level < 1: # base case
        return

    t.down() # put pen down at the start, don't recurse immediately
    t.back(size/2)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(size/2)
    t.left(90)
    draw_shape(t, level - 1, size / 2)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(size)
    t.right(90)
    draw_shape(t, level - 1, size / 2)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(size / 2)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(size)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(size / 2)
    t.left(90)
    draw_shape(t, level - 1, size / 2)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(size)
    t.right(90)
    draw_shape(t, level - 1, size / 2)
    t.right(90)             # add lines below to get back to start position
    t.forward(size / 2)
    t.left(90)
    t.back(size / 2)
```

You could probably simplify this slightly by picking up the pen and skipping from one end of the I to another (e.g. from bottom left to top left) rather than drawing over the middle bar an extra time. I kept most of your code to make the changes that are necessary (rather than just nice) more clear.